# is there statement for assert count a occurrences?

Tags: groovy, assert, assertion

Is there a statement for assert count a range?

Here is an example: I want to make sure a total number of records is 3.

assert the count from first offset to last offset is == 3

or assert the number of times key/value appearing is == 3

**response**

```groovy
[[key:S1BJTzE=, offset:1416, partition:0, topic:Item, value:eyJvcGVyYXRpb2], [key:S1BJTzE=, offset:1417, partition:0, topic:Item, value:eyJvcGVyYXRpb2],
[key:S1BJTzE=, offset:1418, partition:0, topic:Item, value:eyJvcGVyYXRpb2]]
```

I have tried below but getting assertion failed.

```groovy
def test= new JsonSlurper().parseText(test.getResponseText())
println('response text: \n' + test)
assert 3 == test.count("value")
```

Comment: `assert test.size()==3`

Comment: what does it have to do with range?

Answer (score 0):

```
assert test.size()==3
```

contributed by @daggett

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Straight-forward approach:

```
String resp = '[[key:S1BJTzE=, offset:1416, partition:0, topic:Item, value:eyJvcGVyYXRpb2], [key:S1BJTzE=, offset:1417, partition:0, topic:Item, value:eyJvcGVyYXRpb2], [key:S1BJTzE=, offset:1418, partition:0, topic:Item, value:eyJvcGVyYXRpb2]]'
assert 3 == resp.count( 'value:' )
```